# Target micro instance in Flexible AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

Is it possible to target a custom runtime to use a micro instance?

I tried with:

```
resources:
    cpu: 0.5
    memory_gb: 0.6
    disk_size_gb: 10
```

But a small instance is started.

Answer (score 2):

Add following to your `app.yaml`:

```
beta_settings:
  machine_type: f1-micro
```

Comment: Can i use use bta testing like below or not please reply.                                                                           runtime: nodejs
vm: true
# [END runtime]

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
  cool_down_period_sec: 60
  beta_settings:
    machine_type: f1-micro

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: IGNORED
  secure: always

# Temporary setting to keep gcloud from uploading node_modules
skip_files:
- ^node_modules$

Comment: Can i use beta_settings with automatic scaling or not ??

Comment: can you answer my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319880/how-to-set-f1-micro-instance-with-automatic-scaling-in-google-app-engine

Comment: no longer supported... the machine type is derived from your resource settings. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings

Answer (score 0):

In App Engine, the instance type cannot be specified for the flex environment (unlike the standard environment in Python, Java and Go).

In the flex environment, the instance types are *derived* from the resource settings specified in your app.yaml file.

[App Engine Resource Settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings)

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that for some reason the pricing calculator lets you enter small values so the instance appears similar to a F1-micro (I was looking for around $5/month to run it) but then alas when it comes to specifying it in app.yaml it defaults to something that costs a whole lot more than an f1-micro, and you can't set the values to anything lower than what OP shows.

[example very small flex instance in pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=e52760b6-d940-452d-9fee-a1b734abc3a8)